# How do I go about the traversal of Binary Search Trees?

Tags: python, algorithm, binary-search-tree, nodes

I'm trying to print out data by traversing through my Binary Search Tree with both Pre Order Traversal and In Order Traversal.

```
#Pre-Order Traversal
    def preTraverse(node):
        if(node != null):
            print(node)
            preTraverse(node.left)
            preTraverse(node.right)

    #In-Order Traversal
    def inTraverse(node):
        if(node != null):
            inTraverse(node.left)
            print(node)
            inTraverse(node.right)
```

I'm not quite sure if my logic is correct. What would I do if my node is null? Here is my code below(assuming my node class is correct):

Comment: you don't need to do anything for null

Comment: If your node is null you reached a leaf. There is nothing to print and no left or right child nodes.

Comment: You could just have *tried your code* and see if you got correct results. Think up a couple of test cases; what happens if the tree is empty for example.

Comment: If it is empty nothing is printed I think. My other concern is that I'm not sure whether I need to make a Binary search Tree class? I currently have my "insert" function in the Node class.

Comment: in python there is no `null` keyword. you mean `None`. and you can shorten `if node is not None:` to `if node:`